# Setting up and FTP Server using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, sftp

I want to set up a FTP server, so that a 3rd party company could upload files to my server.

I have a Windows WebServer on AWS. So, one option would be to set up FTP on IIS.

Does AWS provide an easier alternative? Perhaps through S3? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS SFTP Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/) might work for you. It backs onto S3 but it runs a server for the FTP interface so it costs a bit more for that server.

You could have the third party to upload files direct to S3. There are some easy enough to use S3 clients, CloudBerry Explorer for example. Just set them up an IAM user.

Comment: Thanks Tim, so the 3rd party would upload to S3...Do you mean I need an IAM user for CouldBerry to read the uploaded files from S3?

Comment: You would create an IAM user for the third party company. The would run CloudBerry (or another S3 client) to log into your account and upload to S3. You would of course use IAM policy to restrict them to one bucket, or one folder in one bucket. This is cheaper than using Amazon sFTP service, if they other company is ok with using something other than FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://storagemadeeasy.com/CloudFTP/ - There's an AMI available to deploy in your VPC directly or VMware/KVM/Hyper-v Virtual appliance that you can use to expose AWS S3 Buckets (as well as other cloud providers as well as NAS) over an SFTP/FTPS interface.

As the administrator you map the storage, then you can create users and groups on the Virtual Appliance (or connect up AD or LDAP). You would then be able to define the permissions allowed for those accounts via the SFTP (ie: they have read only to bucketA and sub folders, read/write to bucketA/prefixB/. And read/write to bucketC/prefixD. for example).

No third party tools required: native SFTP, FTP, FTPS, or even a browser to access (read and write) data stored on AWS S3.